# Receive API body POST by Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, python-requests, google-api-python-client

I have a problem with API POST, can you help me?

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://xxx/api/getTotalPrice'

param = dict(itineraryType=1,
             departureAirportCode='HAN',
             destinationAirportCode='DLI',
             departureDate='2020-12-30T14:00',
             returnDate='2020-12-30T09:00',
             adult=1,
             children=1,
             infant=1
             )

resp = requests.post(url=url, params=param)
u_data = resp.json()
print(u_data)
```

I want to receive data from API POST. This is body API and this made error.

Here, this is error

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    u_data = resp.json()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can get data from POST API without body, but with body, I cannot.
Can you help to fix code?

Many thanks!

P/S:
Here value which I want to get

```
{
    "departureFlight": {
        "totalPrice": 1896000.0,
        "airlineCode": "VN"
    },
    "returnFlight": {
        "totalPrice": 3263800.0,
        "airlineCode": "VJ"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the output value of `resp`?

Comment: I have edit this question. Please check! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have an answer.

```
data = {'itineraryType':1,'departureAirportCode':'HAN','destinationAirportCode':'DLI','departureDate':'2020-12-30T15:00','returnDate':'2020-12-30T09:00','adult':1,'children':1,'infant':1}
headers={'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
resp = requests.post(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)
u_data = resp.json()
print(u_data)
```

change dict(...) to {...} and set headers.